# Google api client calendarv3 event initialization argument error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I'm using google_api_client 0.10.3. I have this call:

```
Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
  'summary' => summary,
  'description' => description,
  'start' => event_datetime(check_out_time),
  'end' =>   event_datetime(check_out_time),
})
```

Somehow I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
from .../gems/google-api-client-0.10.3/generated/google/apis/calendar_v3/classes.rb:964:in `initialize'
```

This is so perplexing, as the class definition in fact takes arguments:

```
def initialize(**args)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use symbols as keys in the hash, not strings.

```
Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
  summary: summary,
  description: description,
  start: event_datetime(check_out_time),
  end: event_datetime(check_out_time),
)
```

In ruby, the double splat operator (`**`) is for capturing *keyword* arguments - which, by design, must always be symbols.